# PHP to MySQL Amazon RDS with SSL, confirm SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm finding lots of conflicting information regarding usage of the MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL flag with a mysql_connect() call, vs setting up and SSH tunnel... Is MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL acceptable? the official documentation seems to indicate yes, but lots of posts on stack and elsewhere say that a tunnel is better but don't explain.

How can I verify that I'm actually getting an encrypted connection if I use MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL? I have added it to my mysql_connect() call and it doesn't throw any errors, I assume it's working, but how can I be sure?

Comment: more certain method is to use a packet sniffer to see what's going out on the wire. If you get random garbage, it's encrypted. If you can see your queries/data going by, then it's not.

Comment: Which is fine if it's all on a local network, but when it's running on a hosted server or a cloud environment it's not really a viable option I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it using this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect([host], [username], [password], false, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL)
    or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher';", $connection);
print_r(mysql_fetch_row($res));
```

The output should look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ssl_cipher
    [1] => xxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxx
)
```

Comment: After trawling through various searches and bug logs, it looks like you might be safer off using mysqli for your SSL requirements. Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

Comment: Thanks, can you provide some details as to why it might be better to use mysqli?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778977/encrypting-mysql-traffic-in-scripts

Comment: Thanks, but that's one of the things that's confusing me. There are claims that it's been abandoned and then someone comes back and points out that it's not. At the end someone says don't use a tunnel because it can drop, and other people are saying you really should use a tunnel...

Comment: If you really want to see if your communication is encrypted, get http://www.wireshark.org/ and grab some packets of data and see if it's plain text or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I had this problem too and solved it so thought I would share my answer for posterity.

[Amazon's docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport) are pretty helpful.  First you need to download the mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem file from Amazon (see the link). Then try to connect from the terminal using that file.

```
mysql --host=mydb.c83ks9ckdk39.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --user=myuser -p --ssl_ca=mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```

Amazon says that you can restrict a connection to SSL by using this grant statement, so run this statement while connected.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' REQUIRE SSL
```

Now disconnect and try to connect again without the "--ssl_ca=mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem" flag.  If you are denied, then you know that SSL connections are now required for this user. Now you just need to setup php correctly. Something like this:

```
$link = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$link->ssl_set(NULL,NULL,"mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem",NULL,NULL); 
$ok = $link->real_connect($MYSQL['host'], $MYSQL['user'], $MYSQL['pass'], $MYSQL['db'], 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

If you can connect then you are connected with SSL and you can run Tom's query to confirm if you want.

```
$rs = $link->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher'");
print_r($rs->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: Command was case sensitive for Ssl_cipher on MYSQL for me: SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';

Comment: Also, I swapped out $con = new mysqli(SESS_DBHOST, SESS_DBUSER, SESS_DBPASS, SESS_DBNAME, SESS_DBPORT); with $con->real_connect(SESS_DBHOST, SESS_DBUSER, SESS_DBPASS, SESS_DBNAME, SESS_DBPORT); so that I could add if (defined('SESS_CERT_CA')) $con->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, SESS_CERT_CA, NULL, NULL); after the $con = mysqli_init(); but before the real_connect.